# Is the 3-cm band serviced by any commercial main-stream ham radio transceiver?

Tags: transceiver, shf

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_band#Amateur_radio) writes to say

> The Radio Regulations of the International Telecommunication Union allow amateur radio operations in the frequency range 10.000 to 10.500 GHz, and amateur satellite operations are allowed in the range 10.450 to 10.500 GHz. This is known as the 3-centimeter band by amateurs and the X-band by AMSAT.

Is the 3-cm band serviced by any commercial main-stream ham radio transceiver?

Comment: The edit makes it answerable, though I believe the answer is no...

Comment: @AdamDavisKD8OAS Well, "no" can certainly be an answer as well, although who knows? [Here's an example](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105549/2465) of a likely correct "no" answer to a question.

Answer (score 5):

None of the major amateur radio manufacturers make a rig for the 3cm band (or most of the microwave bands for that matter).  The common practice is for hams to buy or build a [transverter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverter) which downconverts the received signal from 10GHz to (often) 146MHz and upconverts the transmitted signal from 146MHz to 10GHz.  In essence, 146MHz becomes an Intermediate Frequency for the microwave band radio.

The transverter can be a simple frequency conversion affair or a more complex arrange with pre-amps, amplifies and filters.

For an example of such a device, look at Kuhne Ectronics's [KIT 10 GHz 10G2](http://www.kuhne-electronic.de/en/products/transverter/kit-10-ghz-10g2.html).

Answer (score 4):

At least in Finland you are allowed to use the entire band from 10.0 GHz to 10.5 GHz with "secondary rights". Maximum TX powers are 30 W (basic class) and 150 W. The 3 cm band is also available at least in the USA: http://www.arrl.org/frequency-allocations

Comment: The UK, US, Canada, Australia all allocate this band.  The RSGB calls it, "the most popular frequency range above 23cms".

Comment: @user24368: Just a quick note to convey the question was edited since your answer (+: The meat remains mostly the same though